# JEditorPane get position for character at line and column number

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

How to get the Position, for use with setCaret from a given line and column?

The component has a single font and it is monospaced.  Most other answers I've seen are for determining the line and column number for a given position.  I'm looking for the reverse of this.

I did see JTextComponent.viewToModel but couldn't get far.  There has to be a quick way? :-)

Comment: *"..a given line and column"*  Column?  A column is not applicable to a textual component unless it is using a fixed width font (which they usually don't).  What are you actually trying to achieve from this?  What is the application feature it will be used to support?  Most  importantly, [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  Showing your effort will encourage others to help.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Element` structure of the `Document` to get the starting offset of the specified line and then just add the column that you want to position the Caret at:

```
Element root = component.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
int startOfLineOffset = root.getElement( line - 1 ).getStartOffset();
component.setCaretPosition( startOfLineOffset  + column);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get row height and char width. Use `modelToView()` returned rectangle to get row height and x difference for position 0 and position 1 to get x. 
Then use `viewToModel()` passing `y=rowHeight*rowNumber` and `x=charWidth*colNumber`

Comment: Great idea.  Still seems too complicated to perform such a seemingly simple task.  Oh well, That's Java :-)